# Где ошибка, нужна помощь?

Tags: java, массивы

Нужно проверить массив на возрастание, убывание, одинаковые поля и поля зигзаги(1,2,-1,3,4). Если код работает отдельными частями правильно, то почему-то когда я его компилирую вместе, выдает ошибку(ошибку подсчета). Помогите пж..
Ошибка при проверке массива -

```
[4,4] ожидание false, получение true.
[-10, -3, 17, 17, 30, 31, 42, 111, 122, 3243] ожидание false, получение true.
[3,5] ожидание false, получение true.(если hh ==true и массив возрастает, то возрастает постоянно то есть никаких одинаковых полей и никаких зигзагов)
[5,4] ожидание false, получение true.( если hh = false и массив убывает опять же без никаких одинаковых полей или зигзагов)

public static boolean proverka(int[] in, boolean hh) {
    boolean otw = true;
    if(in == null || in.length == 0) {
        otw = false; 
    } else if (in.length == 1) {
        otw = true;
    } else if (in.length > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length - 3; i++) { 
            if ((in[i] > in[i+1]) && (in[i+1] < in[i+2]) && (in[i+2] > in[i+3])) {
              otw = false;
              break; 
              }
            }
    } else if (in.length > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length - 1; i++) { 
            if (hh == true && in[i] < in[i+1]) {
            otw = true;
            break;
            }
    }
    } else if (in.length > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length -1; i++) {
            if(hh == false && in[i] > in[i+1]) {
                otw = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    } else if (in.length > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length - 2; i++) { 
            if (in[i] == in[i+1]) {
                otw = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    }
    return otw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

После первого `if (in.length > 1)` у тебя `else` никогда не сработает. Переделай через switch  (https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/operator-switch-v-java)

Comment: Почему не сработает?

Comment: И как мне записать условие тогда в этом случае?

Comment: Допустим in.length = 3. Попробуй пройди руками по программе, а можно в дебаггере пошагово. Начни переписывать под switch и (надеюсь) поймешь что нужно поменять в программе. Так же возможно, что я тебя неправильно понял и тебе switch не нужен, тогда поясни вопрос (ЧТО ты хочешь, что бы программа делала). Вполне возможно, что тебе нужно поудалять else и программа заработает.